# Highlight rows in the table by changing color saturation of the row?

Tags: css

I have table and I highlight rows on mouse hover by changing saturation of the row color using this css rows:

```
tr:hover {
    -webkit-filter: saturate(2);
}
```

the CSS above works perfect on chrome but it not works on IE.

So my question is how can I make it work on IE also maybe there is another command  that suitable for both browsers?

Answer (score 0):

The -webkit- prefix identifies this as a browser-targetted property. To make this work in other browsers, the complete syntax is:

```
tr:hover {
    -webkit-filter: saturate(2);
    filter: saturate(2);
}
```

However, note that this doesn't mean it's going to work in every browser - just in those which support the filter property (like for all other CSS3 properties and features). For the documentation and browser compatibility list, check out [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp)